# Can Allegro update the number of joysticks at runtime?

Tags: c++, allegro, joystick

Is there a way to update the number of joysticks plugged in at run-time other than constantly calling `remove_joystick()` then `install_joystick`? This proves to be extremely slow (goes from 60 FPS to around 5).

Allegro 4.2 answers only please...

```
void Joystick::Update() {
    //If joystick input was lost, attempt to reacquire.
    if(GetNumJoysticks() == 0) {
        throw InputNotAvailableException("Joystick");
    }
    //If all joysticks were deleted remove input and do nothing.
    if(_numjoysticks == 0) {
        remove_joystick();
        return;
    }

    //Update state information
    if(poll_joystick() < 0) {
        throw InputNotAvailableException("Joystick");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < _numButtons; ++i) {
        _prevButtons[i].b = _curButtons[i].b;
        _prevButtons[i].name = _curButtons[i].name;

        _curButtons[i].b = joy[_joyNumber].button[i].b;
        _curButtons[i].name = joy[_joyNumber].button[i].name;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < _numSticks; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].num_axis; ++j) {
            _prevSticks[i].axis[j].name = _curSticks[i].axis[j].name;
            _prevSticks[i].axis[j].pos = _curSticks[i].axis[j].pos;
            _prevSticks[i].axis[j].d1 = _curSticks[i].axis[j].d1;
            _prevSticks[i].axis[j].d2 = _curSticks[i].axis[j].d2;

            _curSticks[i].axis[j].name = joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].axis[j].name;
            _curSticks[i].axis[j].pos = joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].axis[j].pos;
            _curSticks[i].axis[j].d1 = joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].axis[j].d1;
            _curSticks[i].axis[j].d2 = joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].axis[j].d2;
        }
        _prevSticks[i].flags = _curSticks[i].flags;
        _prevSticks[i].name = _curSticks[i].name;

        _curSticks[i].flags = joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].flags;
        _curSticks[i].name = joy[_joyNumber].stick[i].name;
    }
}
int Joystick::GetNumJoysticks() {
    remove_joystick();
    if(install_joystick(JOY_TYPE_DIRECTX)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (num_joysticks);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that every frame? Wouldn't it make more sense to do it only as needed?

Comment: @NicolBolas Define "As needed". Seems to me that the joystick needing to be plugged in is "as needed every frame"?

Comment: And what exactly would you do when they plugged one in? Usually, PC games give the user the opportunity to set up their controls as they wish with a configuration UI. This would generally be the time to handle that sort of thing. Or you could stop using the outdated version of Allegro and upgrade to Allegro 5.

Comment: @NicolBolas I wish I could update. I've been invested in this project for about three years and switching to a new, barely-a-year-old, not to mention completely overhauled API and trying to convert over 15,000 lines of code contained in over sixty classes would take a lot more time than it would be worth. Especially if the API changes again. 4.2 works for the time being, albeit with a few workarounds.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess I could go the Microprose route: When the user runs a (if it exists) setup program/method ask them if they want joystick support and store the answer. Future runs would use this answer until it changed when the setup program/method was run again.

Comment: @Casey, Allegro 5 stems from 4.9 which was released in 2006. Since the 5.0 release, API compatibility is now guaranteed again (within the 5 series, of course). At the very least, you should upgrade to 4.4, which is API compatible with 4.2. Obviously upgrading to 5.0 is a chore (although well worth it if you can spare the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4.x series does not. The 5.x series does.

You'll have to either listen for native OS events using custom platform specific code (assuming such things exist) and only call the Allegro deinit/init functions when a change is detected, or require the user to initiate joystick refresh manually.

Under Linux, you could `inotify_add_watch()` /dev/input to check for changes. Looking at the 4.4 Allegro code, looks like you'd want to call the Win32 functions `joyGetNumDevs()` and `joyGetPos()`. Something like:

```
int WIN_MAX_JOYSTICKS = joyGetNumDevs(); // this should never change
JOYINFO ji;
int pluggedin_count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < WIN_MAX_JOYSTICKS; ++i)
  if (joyGetPos(i, &ji) == JOYERR_NOERROR) ++pluggedin_count;

if (pluggedin_count != last_pluggedin_count) /* reinit Allegro */
```

You'd have to do that every N seconds.

Those joy* functions are Windows functions, so read MSDN docs to learn how to use them.

Comment: Oh poo... Well, there goes the idea of implementing an optional joystick at run-time. The user is just going to have to deal and plug it in before starting the game.

Comment: I've added some examples of how you might go about implementing a real time scan, but I'd recommend just limiting these to a config or title screen.